# Cannot connect to localhost:8082

Tags: maven, localhost

After successful running the maven project in eclipse, I cannot connect to `http://localhost:8082`. It shows the below error:

> connection refused

What should I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when there is no service listening on the port you are trying to connect to. A couple of things could be happening:

- You have not started your server.
- Your server is not waiting to
  accept connections.
- You are trying to connect to the wrong port
  number.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your services. I think they are either stopped or not working. You can check the services:-
a) if using windows by clicking services in control panel
b) if using linux type in the command Line sudo mqsql service.
you can refer this link- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-if-mysql-is-running-on-linux/

2)Also check the database connection string might you have not used correct string.